# How do C++ progs get their return value, when a return is not specified in the function?

Tags: c++, memory, return-value, return

I recently wrote a post:
[Weird Error in C++ Program: Removing Printout Breaks Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452355/weird-error-in-c-program-removing-printout-breaks-program)

...in which I was trying to solve a seemingly baffling problem, in which removing a cout statement would break my program.

As it turned out, my problem was that I forgot to return my true/false success flag that I was later using for logic.

But apparently SOMETHING was being returned and that something was always true if I left that cout in, but would seemingly "magically" become false when I took it out.

My question for you all is: 
**What determines what a c++ function return when no return command is executed within the function?  Is there any logic to it?**

Obviously forgetting your return type is a bad idea.  In this case, though, it was largely due to the nature of my program -- a quick hack job.  I later decided that it wasn't worth the effort to include implement an algorithm to determine the success/failure of the function call -- but accidentally left behind the code dependent on the return.

Bafflingly g++ gave me no warnings or errors when compiling the executable like so:

```
g++ main.cc -g -o it_util
```

My version is:
g++ (GCC) **4.1.2 20080704** (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

Again, to save others future frustration in case they make the same silly mistake and are met with the same seemingly erratic behavior, can anyone cast light on where a function without a return gets its return value from??

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if you compile with the `-Wall` flag?

Comment: From whatever happens to be on `eax`, I suppose?

Comment: The return value is machine/architecture specific. If you whistle-blow on what operating system/computer/compiler combo you work (32bit/64bit) and of what type is the expected return value (int, structure, pointer, floating point), somebody might help you out here.

Regards

rbo

Comment: Good point, Neil.  I get the warning `main.cc:278: warning: control reaches end of non-void function` when I turn on the -Wall flag, so I guess g++ *does* warn me, but simply turns off that warning by default.  Guess I should probably remember to use that flag next time, eh?

Comment: @Jason You should set your environment up so that you use -Wall every time - probably add -Wextra and -pedantic too. These  will save you lots of time.

Comment: I'm very surprised that isn't a default warning... that's so bad, it almost deserves to be considered an error (I'd imagine the only reason it isn't an error is because the language spec allows it.  I can't imagine a circumstance where it could be desired).

Comment: Exactly, I was very surprised that it wasn't a standard warning... thanks for the advice Neil, I'll alias my g++ to use that, for when I'm doing small builds sans makefiles...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On x86 calling conventions, the return value for integers and pointers is on the EAX register. The following is an example of that:

```
int func() {
    if(0) return 5; // otherwise error C4716: 'func' : must return a value
}
int main() {
    int a;
    a = func();
}
```

Compiling with `cl.exe /Zi`, MSVC++10:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ecx
call    j_?func@@YAHXZ  ; func(void)
mov     [ebp+a], eax ; assumes eax contains the return value
xor     eax, eax
mov     esp, ebp
pop     ebp
retn
```

Of course, this is all undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

There is no logic to it, and most C++ compilers should flag it with a warning. It allowed for backward-compatibility to C.

In K&R C, there was no `void` type, and when a type was unspecified, it default to `int`.  So,

```
myfunc() {....}
```

Was techincally a function returning a int, but most programmers used that form for a routine not returning a value.

The compiler had to make sense of this.  So, the convention became, the `return` would put something into a register. And the assignment in the calling routine would take the value out of the register. Now, if the callee never issued a return, nothing *specific* would be placed in that register.  But it would still have *some* (random) value in it, which would be blindly assigned in the caller.

Answer (score 4):

From C++ Standard section *6.6.3 The return statement*

> Flowing off the end of a function is
>   equivalent to a return with no value;
>   this results in undefined behavior in
>   a value-returning function.

There is one exception (as per 3.6.1/5):

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return
>   statement, the effect is that of
>   executing return 0;

The reason this is syntactically allowed is put nicely by [James Curran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12725/james-curran). But with the **-Wall** gcc option (as commented by Neil) you should be warned on this behavior; something like 'Not all control paths return value in a value-returning function...'.

Comment: Is there any case where this is desirable behavior in modern c++?  Why is there no warning by default (i.e. why do you have to turn on -Wall in g++ to see the error?)?

Comment: @Jason: Imagine you have a template function `template<class T> T func() { return ; } template<> int func() { return 1; } template<class T> T func1() { return func<T>(); } int main() { func<void>(); func<int>(); return 0; }` 
Now the compiler cannot complain based just on the `return` keyword, can it ?

Comment: @Jason: g++ gives no warnings by default. That's just the way it is.

Comment: There is one exception (3.6.1/5): If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the calling convention. For instance, for a 32-bit integer return on an Intel platform, you get whatever is in the `eax` register.

Answer (score 0):

With a modern compiler you'll probably get an Warning using -Wall

But if you don't return a value, usually you'll get garbage.

Answer (score 0):

"What determines what a c++ function return when no return command is executed within the function? Is there any logic to it?"

The type in the beginning of the function.

Example:

**int** cow()
{
int temp;
return temp;
}

If you don't return the correct type or return nothing, the compiler should complain. **Edit:** Oh crap, I've just read your flags. You need to turn on more flags man, -W -Wall -pedantic. Read the g++ manual.

Unless you have a void function. Then you don't have to return anything or you can have pointer to play.

void somefunction( int* ptr_int)
{
  int temp = *ptr_int;
  temp +=1000;
  this->ptr_int = temp;
}

I believe the above code works, it have been awhile since I've coded in C++.