# How could this bool method compile without errors?

Tags: c++

I have this method in my C++ program, in Visual Studio 2012, standard compiler:

```
bool FPS::frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent &evt) {
    bool result = BaseApplication::frameRenderingQueued(evt);
    if (!result) {
        Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().logMessage("Exiting, result of frame rendereing queued: " + result);
        return result;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < 20; z++) {
            robotAnimation[x][z]->addTime(evt.timeSinceLastFrame);
            tileSceneNode[x][z]->translate(tileSceneNode[x][z]->getOrientation() * Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_X * 35.0f * evt.timeSinceLastFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

How could it compile without giving any errors? I mind you that the result cannot be predictable.

When I ran it, this happened: The function itself returned `false` (as Ogre shuts down if `frameRenderingQueued()` returns `false`. However the branch `if (!result) { ... }` has never been reached. So the behaviour was unpredictable.

Later when I added `return true;` at the end of the function, everything was working as expected.

So how could this broken method compile just fine?

Comment: It's undefined behavior as not all of your branches return a value. You should turn on all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not required to diagnose that error, since in general it's impossible for static analysis to determine whether a sufficiently complicated function can run off the end. Instead, you get undefined behaviour.

Hopefully, your compiler will give a warning in this case, if you have warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have warnings turned off? For me, in VS2012 a similar function produces:

`warning C4715: 'frameRenderingQueued' : not all control paths return a value`

Comment: I indeed got that warning (wasn't able to check until now), however sadly the build log is a bit cluttered as one header file from OGRE issues quite some warnings, hence I haven't been paying that much attention.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is undefined. This should be an error in compilers but never is. You should turn on warnings for your compiler.

Read about exactly why it is undefined behaviour here.
[How do C++ progs get their return value, when a return is not specified in the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459810/how-do-c-progs-get-their-return-value-when-a-return-is-not-specified-in-the-f)

Answer (score 0):

Running off the end of a non-void function is undefined
behavior.  That means that the compiler is not required to issue
a diagnostic, and that it must compile the code unless it can
prove that you must inevitably run off the end, which is usually
impossible.  (Imagine, for example, that
`BaseApplication::frameRenderingQueued` always returns `false`,
or that the function you call with
`tileSceneNode[x][z]->translate(...)` always throws an
exception.)

Most compilers will warn about code like the above.  You should
activate the warnings, and pay attention to them.